# How to free an object from within one of its own methods?

Tags: delphi, object, memory-management

Is there a way to safely free an object from within one of its own methods? (I don't need to nil the objects variable)

```
var
  Msg: TAMessage;
begin
  Msg := TAMessage.Create();
  Msg.ProcessAndDone;
end;
```

And I want `TAMessage.ProcessAndDone()` method to destroy the object itself (in the above case `Msg`) because I won't need the object after calling `ProcessAndDone` method, and I don't want to call `Free` or `Destroy` each time right after I call `ProcessAndDone` (for the sake of code clarity).

I know setting a TThread's `FreeOnTerminate` property does this but the actual freeing process is handled by a wrapper called ThreadProc which calls thread's `Execute` within.

Comment: If you need a self-destructing object you should use an `interface` and a reference-counted implementation (e.g. `TInterfacedObject`) implementing this interface. It will do so once you forget it (`nil` the reference to the interface)

Comment: Your claim about the main thread freeing a `TThread` when `FreeOnTerminate=True` is wrong. `TThread` frees itself within its own context after its `DoTerminate()` method has exited.

Comment: Thanks for the correction Remy. I've also updated the last paragraph in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the very last act of `ProcessAndDone` is to call `Destroy`, or `Free`, then it is fine. If `ProcessAndDone` calls methods, or refers to members, after it has been destroyed, then it's no good. And of course, you'd need to put a `try/finally` inside `ProcessAndDone` to make sure the destruction happens.

But all that said, you should not do this. Patterns exist for clarity, and for the benefit of other readers. Whenever we see

```
obj := TMyObject.Create;
```

we also expect to see a `try/finally` block with a call to `Free`. Don't go against the grain.